# bootstrap 4.5.3 centering navbar text with icon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have navbar with two menu, want to center menu icon and text but i dont't find the class to used.
how can i do it ?
im sorry for my bad english

here my code

```
  <body class="text-center">
     <div class="bg-login">
        <div class="container">
           <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top h-100">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto nav-fill">
                 <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navlink">
                    <span data-feather="globe"></span>
                    EN-US
                    </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <span data-feather="globe"></span>
                    en-uk
                    </a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        feather.replace()
     </script>
  </body>
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/lexavey/jywL5ves/12/

im use

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto nav-fill">`

because i want navigation i right side like this https://prnt.sc/wb1d3s

my problem is center verticaly https://prnt.sc/wb1hp1

Answer (score 0):

add flex classes to the container div

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
```

Comment: icon and text now is centered, but i want navbar location still in right position like this https://prnt.sc/wb1d3s

Answer (score 0):

You can use these classes in Nav elements

```
<a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#" id="navlink">
```

Comment: im use ml-auto for make navigation in right side, i update my question

Comment: icon problem is done , now text problem still not center , also i need space between icon and text, https://prnt.sc/wb1tal